# R Shiny module: input not updated with uiOutput / renderUI inside callModule

Tags: r, module, shiny

I've been searching around and cannot find an answer to my question. I've constructed a simple app to demonstrate my problem. Basically, the problem is that I am trying to use a `renderUI` inside my module server to conditionally create a `uiOutput` in the module UI. I've included a few `print` statements that lead me to believe that the `renderUI` is evaluated without `input` being updated. It is killing me that I can't figure this out, and I'd appreciate any help possible!

Example code:

```
library(shiny) # shiny_1.0.0
library(DT) # DT_0.2

testModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns = NS(id)

  tagList(
    br(),
    sidebarPanel(width = 12, id = "inputBar",
                 fluidRow(
                   column(width = 2, checkboxInput(ns("buttonA"), label = "Button A", value = F)),
                   column(width = 2, uiOutput(ns("getButtonB")))
                 ),
                 dataTableOutput(outputId = ns("tableOutput"))
    )
  )
}

testModule <- function(input, output, session, showB = F ){
  ns = session$ns

  output$getButtonB <- renderUI({
    if( showB ){
      print("call checkboxInput")
      checkboxInput(ns("buttonB"), label = "Button B", value = F)
    }else{
      NULL
    }
  })

  getTable <- reactive({
    print("inside getTable")
    out = c()

    if( input$buttonA ) {
      out = paste0(out, "A")
    } 

    if( input$buttonB ){
      out = paste0(out, "B")
    }

    data.frame(var = out)
  })

  output$tableOutput <- renderDataTable({
    print("call getTable")
    datatable( getTable() )
  })

}


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule( module = testModule, id = "test1", showB = T )

  session$onSessionEnded( stopApp )
}


ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel( title = "Test app" ),

  sidebarPanel(
    width = 3,
    selectInput(inputId = "whatever", label = "This button doesn't matter", choices = c("A", "B"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1", testModuleUI("test1"))
    )
  )
)

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser = T)
```

)

Thank you!!

Comment: Just add `req(input$buttonB)` (after `print("inside getTable")`)

Comment: @HubertL - That actually makes it worse because then button A never works independently. I have tried adding `req()` statements, but they only stop the code, they don't force the evaluation of the input inside them. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: why don't you just use `if(!is.null(input$buttonB))`before `if( input$buttonB ){`

Comment: @HubertL - thank you, that did the trick! However, I still do not understand why is this necessary? It also forces the evaluation of getTable() twice when the app first begins, which is not ideal. Is there a reason the inputs take a second pass of getTable to update?